# Custom Vibrations in iOS 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I need my iPhone to have custom vibrations as in Custom Vibrations feature in iOS 5

I've tried functions from CoreTelephony.framework

```
_CTServerConnectionCreate(....)
_CTServerConnectionSetVibratorState(....)
```

But this are private methods and I couldn't make them work.

Comment: No errors during compilation the code is as follows:


connection =_CTServerConnectionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,&vibratecallback, &x);    

_CTServerConnectionSetVibratorState(&x, connection, 3, 3., 0., 0., 0.);

usleep(500000);

_CTServerConnectionSetVibratorState(&x, connection, 0, 0., 0., 0., 0.);

Comment: Do you know where to read about this functions arguments? Simple google search gives no result. Thanks!

Comment: Did you activate custom vibrations on your device? I know this might be a silly question but just to make sure.

Comment: Yes but I don't think you need to activate custom vibrations to use this methods.

Comment: It seems like this methods are private, and cos rejection.
Does iOS 5 provide any API functions to create or use your own vibrations?